# Issue with crash report in play developer console

Tags: android, crash, google-play, google-play-developer-api, developer-console

I recently received a crash report in Play Developer Console for my app.

However, I found myself unable to diagnose the issue as the stack traces in the crash report point to a class which are not there in my app.

The stack trace in the crash report is this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.VideoView.pause()' on a null object reference
at packagename.e.b(Unknown Source)
at packagename.e.a(Unknown Source)
at packagename.e.onScroll(Unknown Source)
at android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(GestureDetector.java:567)
at android.support.v4.h.u.a(Unknown Source)
at android.support.v4.h.q.a(Unknown Source)
at packagename.f.onTouch(Unknown Source)
at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8503)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2540)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2225)
at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8715)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4520)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4378)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3959)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3925)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4035)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3933)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4092)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3959)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3925)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3933)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3906)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6349)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6305)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6258)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6511)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:185)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.nativeConsumeBatchedInputEvents(Native Method)
at android.view.InputEventReceiver.consumeBatchedInputEvents(InputEventReceiver.java:176)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doConsumeBatchedInput(ViewRootImpl.java:6470)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ConsumeBatchedInputRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6542)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:800)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:603)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:570)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:786)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:956)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:751)
```

As you can see in the stack traces, the error occured in the class `e` and I don't have any classes named `e` or `f` in my app.

Can anyone help me to understand and diagnose this issue?

Comment: Did you use proguard in your application?

Comment: Not sure. But I think, yes. As the minifyEnabled is set to true in gradle.

Comment: so that may be obfuscate your class file thats why it is giving you e and f such name in the application.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by obfuscating the class files. Can you help me in diagnosing where the error occured?

Comment: Do you have VideoView in your application?

Comment: Yes, I'm using videoview along with gesturedetector in two activities. That's the problem I can't identify in which activity the error occured.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106887/discussion-between-silvans-solanki-and-shivam-arora).